# How to make inline blocks on multiple lines display nicely

Tags: html, css

Let's say that I have this structure on my website:

```css
.elem {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px dotted blue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="elem">Some content on 1 line</div>
  <div class="elem">Some content on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
  <div class="elem">Some content on 2 lines<br>second line</div>
  <div class="elem">Some content2 on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
  <div class="elem">Some content2 on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
  <div class="elem">Some content2 on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: content]

Let's say that the browser is big enough so there can be 3 divs in each column. I want the 4th div to appear on the first column and on the second row. I don't know how big the individual divs might be (in height, I can set the width later on) so I can't hardcode a height into each divs.

How can I do this so they would align? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use flex instead of floats

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try inline-flex like this,

```css
.elem {
  border: 2px dotted blue;
  display: inline-flex;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="elem">Some content on 1 line</div>
  <div class="elem">Some content on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
  <div class="elem">Some content on 2 lines<br>second line</div>
  <div class="elem">Some content2 on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
  <div class="elem">Some content2 on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
  <div class="elem">Some content2 on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can play with flex to get the desired results.

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.elem {
    border: 2px dotted blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="elem">Some content on 1 line</div>
    <div class="elem">Some content on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
    <div class="elem">Some content on 2 lines<br>second line</div>
    <div class="elem">Some content2 on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
    <div class="elem">Some content2 on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
    <div class="elem">Some content2 on 3 lines<br>second line<br>third line</div>
</div>
```